# Questions on Down votes

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes

When down voting an answer, I see that I do not need to give a reason if I don't want to (Though I always make sure to let them know what is wrong). Why don't we make a rule where users have to give feedback when down voting a post?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106818) question [comes up](https://meta.superuser.com/a/7224) a [lot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177). Like, [a lot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138977).  On [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215422), on [other](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1372) SE [sites](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1184) all around [the network](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/647), and—yes—even right [here on Puzzling Meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1660).  I mean, ***[really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=require+downvote+comment&submit=search)*** a ***[lot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=require+downvote+comment&submit=search)***.
And it's always rejected, and for good reasons.

The semi-canonical reason why there is not such a rule can be found in the expansive answer to
[Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437) on StackOverflow Meta; it's slightly StackOverflow-specific, but most of it applies to all SE sites.  In short, downvotes are expressly anonymous and intentionally made to not require much effort to do; in particular, a downvote should not involve jumping through any more hoops to cast than an upvote, as there shouldn't be a higher psychological cost to giving a post a deserved downvote than there would be for giving an upvote.

Feel free to peruse the many prior questions and answers for voluminous other words on the subject.

Comment: Hmm, I'll take a look that that link you gave. Thx for explaining though :D